# Tailwind css don't show hover state when input is in focus

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

On the following div:

```
<div className='border border-gray-400 
                text-gray-600 
                hover:border-gray-600 
                focus:border-green-500 
                focus-within:border-green-500'>
```

I want the hover state not to happen when an element is an in-focus state. How can I make it so?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try `:not`? I am no expert in tailwind css

Comment: Can I add it as answer and would you upvote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the css `:not` selector, e.g. `hover(:not focus):border-gray-600`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with conflicting `:hover` and `:focus-within`, so my solution was to use `:hover:focus-within` like this `hover:border-gray-600 focus-within:border-green-500 hover:focus-within:border-green-500`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, `border` need to define width, so in this example I gave just 2 when it hovered.
check official [Doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states)

```
<div className='hover:border-2 border-gray-400 text-gray-600 
                    hover:border-gray-600 
                    focus:border-green-500 focus-within:border-green-500'>
```

Comment: Nope, still overriding focus style when hovering

Comment: could u check in here? https://play.tailwindcss.com/CiKlgdMI4W

Comment: I advise you to use separate hover and focus and put them in separate divs or elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const FramelessInput = ({ name }) => {
const [focused, setFocused] = useState(false);
return (
    <div
        className={classNames(
            'w-[200px] rounded-sm border border-transparent text-gray-600  focus-within:border-green-500',
            !focused && 'hover:border-gray-600'
        )}
    >
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder={name}
            onFocus={(e) => setFocused(true)}
            onBlur={(e) => setFocused(false)}
            className="block text-sm leading-4 font-sans p-3 h-10 focus:outline-none"
        />
    </div>
);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Try use property "ring"

```html
<div className='border border-gray-400 
                text-gray-600 
                ring-green-500 
                focus-within:ring-2'>
```